# How can I limit each RDD partition to 'n' records only?

Tags: java, apache-spark

Is there a way where I can specify each JavRDD partition to have only 'n' number of records?

```
 JavaRDD<String> res = rdd.mapPartitions((Iterator<String> iter) -> {
            Iterable<String> iterable = () -> iter;
            return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
                    .map(s -> Dummy.getResponse(s, b))
                    .iterator();
        });
```

Comment: use `mapPartitions` and limit the iterator to N items

Comment: I am using `mapPartitions`. Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many records you have you can deduce number of partitions you need to hold n records and then use `rdd.repartition(number of partitions)`

Refer here : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@repartition(numPartitions:Int)(implicitord:Ordering[T]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]